# Lauch RDP and login and keep running?

Tags: if-statement, desktop

I need a script that can run an RDP file at login, and keep running..

Wait until the user has logged off from the remote session, and relaunch the RDP file.

Im thinking look in tasklist for mstsc.exe and use an IF statement if it is or is not running?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RDPv1

static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    RDP(); 
    while(true) 
    { 
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) 
        { 
            if (!clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("mstsc.exe")) 
            { 
                RDP(); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        Thread.sleep(300);///Use any value which is confortable with you're request 
    } 
} 

private static void RDP() 
{ 
    Process rdp = new Process(); 
    rdp.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\RDP.rdp"); 
    rdp.Start(); `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please don't close this box!");
            RDP();
            while (true)
            {
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").Length == 0)
                {
                    RDP();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void RDP()
        {
            Process rdp = new Process();
            rdp.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\RDP\\rdp.rdp");
            rdp.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it launches the rdp and then goes into an infinite loop checking if the process is running, if it isn't then it launches it again.

To put it into VS just open VS C#, start a new Console Application and paste the above in. Then press the green triangle and it will run the program, to find the EXE of it, it's usually in Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\Your Project Name\Your Project Name\bin\Debug

Credit to Cody for helping with this script earlier

Comment: Im sorry, ive only ever used BAT and VBS... Im happy to use your solution but I have no idea how to!

Comment: Ok, if you use BAT you could maybe do something like this: tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mstsc.exe" if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo rdp is still running else rdppath. You could then put this into a for loop? I haven't done much with for in batch but maybe for /? will help you

Comment: @fairm010 If you want to use the C# code then just install Visual Studio 2010 (Express is free) put the code in and compile it, happy to help if you need any

Comment: Just downloading Visual Studio now... Will let you know!

Comment: Cool, make sure you get the version with C#, there are different versions with C++ and VB

Comment: I gave it a shot, all sorts of errors, plus I dont have a clue what i'm doing!

Comment: Ok, I am still working on this code, should be done soon, I will make sure you get it working :D

Comment: The only bit you need to change is the path to the rdp file - near the bottom.

Comment: I get this error, any ideas? Visual Studio cannot start because the debug target "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RDP\RDP\RDP\bin\Debug\RDP.exe is missing. Please build the project and try again or set the output path and Assemblyname appropriately to point at the correct location fore the target assembly.

Comment: I think your path has an extra RDP folder, should only be 2 with that name, try outputting it to somewhere different - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hmmm, outputting it to the desktop makes no difference... I have changed the OutputPath and the Assembly Name :/

Comment: Make sure that the Assembly name has no spaces. Other than that I'm not sure, possibly re - create the project? Failing that ask another question about that, there will be plently of VS experts here I'm sure!

Comment: Sure, but you need to show me what you want to check :D, if it's code then maybe edit or add to your original question so you can use the programming text format?

Comment: Sorry :P Its in the original question! :)

Comment: Ok, edited on both answers as not sure how long it takes to see the edit I made on yours :)

Comment: Use the code in my current answer, the edit in your answer doesn't seem to have worked for some reason... I have made a few changes and this works perfectly.

Comment: I get this error when pressing the green triangle like you said

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the class, copy everything in my answer now and it is working, just tried it myself, the code is flawless so if it isn't working it might be a visual studio error, might be worth posting another question, I'm afraid thats about as much as I can do code wise...

Comment: Yes, at what point do you want to write in it? i.e When it first opens, when the rdp has been re - opened etc.

Comment: When it first opens, it would be great if I could have in there what it does, so that the staff don't close it!

Comment: Sure, if you put Console.WriteLine("your message"); outside the loop at the start it should stay there as long as it is open, I've added it into my answer